# Trouble getting python selenium tests to run

Tags: python, selenium, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation

I am creating an automation framework from scratch using selenium with python and would really like some input and advice on the best way to do so.

So far I have the following but my test script will not run. Please help!

script.py

```
from selenium import webdriver


class WebDriver(object):

  def __init__(self, driver=None):
    """
    __init__ setup webdriver test script class
    """
    self.driver = driver


  def setup(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

  def teardown(self):
    self.driver.quit()
```

test.py

```
import script

class Test(script.WebDriver):

  def search(self):
    self.driver.get("www.google.com")
    self.driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib").clear()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "will not run"? Is there an exception? Any logs to show?

Comment: No errors, simply doesn't open the browser. Nothing happens

Comment: It doesn't appear that anything is trying to create an instance of `Test`. Is this all your code? How are you running the test -- directly with `python test.py` or indirectly through a testing framework?

Comment: directly with python test.py

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are trying to run this with [python unittest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html). If so, your class should inherit from `unittest.TestCase` in order to mark that it contains test cases:

```
class WebDriver(unittest.TestCase)

...

class Test(script.WebDriver)
```

And second missing piece is "boiler plate code to run the test suite" (see explanation [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/getting-started.html#using-selenium-to-write-tests)) in `test.py`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   test.main()
```